# Using a custom event for a v-dialog activator in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I am currently using Vuetify for an application that has a series of `v-dialog` components.

I currently have:

```
                    <template v-if="topic">
                        <v-dialog v-model="removeTagDialogs[removeTagDialogs.indexOf(tag.id)]" v-for="(tag, iii) in topic.tags" :key="iii" persistent max-width="200">
                            <template v-slot:activator="{ on, attrs }">
                                <v-chip close color="primary" text-color="white" class="mr-1" v-bind="attrs" v-on="on">{{ tag.name.en }}</v-chip>
                            </template>

                            <v-card>
                                <v-card-title class="error--text text-center">Remove Tag?</v-card-title>
                                <v-card-actions>
                                    <v-btn color="error" @click="removeTagDialogs[removeTagDialogs.indexOf(tag.id)] = false">Cancel <v-icon small color="white">mdi-cancel</v-icon></v-btn>
                                    <v-btn color="error" @click="removeTag(tag.id)">Remove <v-icon small color="white">mdi-delete</v-icon></v-btn>
                                </v-card-actions>
                            </v-card>
                        </v-dialog>
                    </template>
```

Which works fine, however the dialog is enabled only when I click on the main portion of the badge component, and not on the close icon. I need to change it to the other way around, where the dialog is opened when the close icon is pressed.

I tried modifying the `v-on` property to use the `click:close` event directly however it does not work.

```
<v-chip close color="primary" text-color="white" class="mr-1" v-bind="attrs" v-on="click:close">{{ tag.name.en }}</v-chip>
```

How would I modify this to open the dialog on the `click:close` event?

Answer (score 0):

Try to destruct the `on` slot prop then run that destructed `click` as hanlder of `click:close` event:

```
<template v-slot:activator="{ on: { click }, attrs }">
     <v-chip ... @click:close="click">{{ tag.name.en }}</v-chip>
</template>
```

inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63955558/8172857)

Comment: That has no affect.